# multiple operations using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I want to perform an operation and simultaneously show the progress in HTML5 and JavaScript. Since I am using IE 8, the `<progress>` element is not supported, the approach I thought of is using a jQuery AJAX method like this:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" id="id" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    <span class="sr-only">Complete</span>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            url: "Perform a server side operation", 
            success: function(result){
                ProgressBarUpdate(20);
            }
        });
    });
});

var ProgressBarUpdate = function(value) {
    value = value + 10;
    $("#id").css("width", value +"%");
}
```

But the issue here is how to perform the operation and update the progress bar simultaneously? Because after coming to `success:` part of the AJAX request, directly showing `100%` progress doesn't make sense. Is there any other approach available for this?

Comment: What action are you doing on server side ? if you are uploading any file then by using `$.ajaxSettings.xhr().upload();` you can get the uplaoding percentage

Comment: I wanted to do the same in my project.But this isnt possible as it is a ajax call and you cant get the progress of it in true sense.You can make a fake(illusion) of a progressbar but thats not the actual progress:(

Comment: I am makking it as a generic component not necessarily upload

Comment: you can use [progressbar](https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload with example: http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-progress-bar-for-php-ajax-file-upload/ - Check out `uploadProgress` and its `percentComplete`.

Comment: while taking multiple ajax results in same time, the first result is not the first sent ajax, the first result is the first completed.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the operation is taking place server side, I know of two approaches.

**Polling**

This will take place with a different ajax

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax("checkprogress.url", function(data){
       $('.progress-bar').val(data);
}, 1000);
```

Basically, you will poll a server-side service/script/code every interval and the response will contain the current progress. You will then update the progress bar.

**WebSockets**

Another approach is to use a web-socket framework which will allow you to **push** content(progress updates) and/or implement a  [remote procedure call](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738291(v=ws.10).aspx) to conected clients in real-time.

Two such frameworks are [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/)